linux get executable name of active window in c++
I'm trying to create a plugin that will perform arbitrary functions based on the executable name of currently active window.
I know how to get the window name from command line using this command:
ps -p $(xprop -id $(xprop -root '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f2) '\t$0' _NET_WM_PID | cut -f2) -o comm=
But I want to avoid calling external programs that might or might not be available.
I've seen some people executing similar command with system calls or exec and then returning the console output back to some variable. Saw some examples in python too.
What would be an elegant way of doing the same but within a C++ code? Some X11 voodoo? d-bus? I don't even know where to start looking. I failed to google for anything I could use.
A stretch goal would be to also detect window focus change and only check the active window executable on this change event.

I have tagged x11 since that seems to be the windowing system that you are asking about. If you are asking about something else (e.g. wayland) then please tag as appropriate.

You could take a look at the xprop source code where the active ingredient seems to be calls to XGetWindowProperty...

I will certainly take a look at this. thank you.
